# How can I add validation in textformfield in listviewbuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a dynamic textformfield using Listviewbuilder :-

(1). I want to add validation in mobile field
(2). I want to add validation in name field

But in dynamic condition my validation is not working properly.

Comment: share with us what u've done so far

Answer (score 1):

First store your fields validation in a Map like below.

> Map contains 'key' as fields name and 'values' as validator functions.

> ```
> Map<String, String? Function(String?)?> formFields = {
>       'username': (String? value) {
>         return (value!.isEmpty) ? 'Can not be Empty' : null;
>       },
>       'password': (String? value) {
>         return (value == null || value!.length < 8)
>             ? 'Must be 8 Char Long'
>             : null;
>       },
>     };
> ```

Use the Map key to access validator functions.

> formFields[formFields.keys.elementAt(index)]

And then use ListView.builder to generate multiple TextFormFields like below.

> ```
> ListView.builder(
>                   itemCount: formFields.length,
>                   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>                     return TextFormField(
>                       decoration: InputDecoration(
>                         labelText: formFields.keys.elementAt(
>                             index), // this gives key String ('username', 'password')
>                       ),
>                       onSaved: (String? value) {},
>                       validator: formFields[formFields.keys.elementAt(index)],
>                     );
>                   },
>                 ),
> ```

For different type of Form Elements lets say TextFormField, DropdownButtonFormField you could directly add these widgets on the MAP instead of Validator only.

> ```
>  Map<String, String? Function(String?)?> formFields = {
>       'username': TextFormField(
>                       decoration: InputDecoration(
>                         labelText: formFields.keys.elementAt(
>                             index), // this gives key String ('username', 'password')
>                       ),
>                       onSaved: (String? value) {},
>                       validator: TextFormField(
>                       decoration: InputDecoration(
>                         labelText: formFields.keys.elementAt(
>                             index), // this gives key String ('username', 'password')
>                       ),
>                       onSaved: (String? value) {},
>                       validator: (String? value) {
>     return (value!.isEmpty) ? 'Can not be Empty' : null;
>   },
>                     );,
>                     );,
>    );
> ```